Whirlpool ice maker not making ice

Whirlpool upright freezer, model  WSZ57L18DM01
Ice maker model ECKMF94 or 95, replaced about two years ago.

The machinery all runs like it thinks it's making ice - the fingers rotate normally - but no ice is actually produced.
I removed the solenoid valve, disconnected the tubing, and verified that the water supply is good, and there's nothing blocking the tubing between the valve and the ice maker.
The solenoid showed about 270Ω on my multimeter. Some sites say that's too much, and others say it's allowed to be as high as 600Ω, so I guess I don't know if the solenoid is bad or not. A new one will cost $35-50.
I guess some plumbing in the ice maker itself could be plugged up, but I don't know where to start looking there.
I'd rather not replace the ice maker again if I don't have to; it's only two years old, and a replacement is about $130. (I'm not sure whether that includes a new solenoid valve.)
I asked my dad the tightwad what he thinks, and he told me to invest in ice cube trays. (But nobody ever fills those up!)
So, any ideas?
Update: Replaced the solenoid valve and its outlet tube. No joy. I guess the controller is next.
Update: cut the end off an extension cord and used it to verify that the solenoid valve is working and water is getting to the ice maker when the valve opens. So maybe the freezer isn't telling the valve to open?

The metal ones with the lever are a good investment.  They last forever.

@crip659 ...as long as somebody remembers to fill them.

There's not any plumbing in the ice maker. There is a tube out the back of the freezer that the water comes out of and dumps into the ice maker. Sounds like no water is going into the ice maker. If there was, it would freeze and the little fingers would rotate and dump out the ice.

@JACK That's pretty much what I figured. It's just about got to be the solenoid valve.

Not sure what your skill set is but to test the valve, I use a 120V cord with alligator clips on the end. Unplug the valve from the refrig wiring and hook the clips on to the valve. Plug in the cord and see if the water comes out into the ice maker.

@JACK That's a good idea...I'll give it a try.

Do you have water in the tube TO the icemaker?

@Huesmann I thought so, but I'll check again to be sure.

So is water now getting into the ice maker?  If so, is it freezing?

I just verified that the solenoid works and water gets to the ice maker when the valve opens. So maybe the freezer isn't telling the valve to open?

@BeerMe  So let the water freeze and see if the ice maker completes the cycle.

@JACK The cycle completes, but no ice comes out. Everything in the freezer is frozen, so I would expect the water to freeze too.

@BeerMe  So if the water you put in the ice maker freezes and then the ice maker completes the cycle, ice should be falling into the bin. If the frozen water in the ice maker doesn't fall out, then the ice maker isn't ejecting the ice.  Your motor probably isn't working under load.

@JACK Thanks, I'll look into that. It's kinda sounding like I'll have to replace the ice maker again.

I am a peabrain.
I bought a new icemaker. As I was uninstalling the old one, I noticed that the very end of the tube, just before the water would fall into the machine, had a 2cm plug of ice.
So I melted that plug, put it all back together, and it's making ice by the bucketful.
So whoever suggested that I check for ice in the fill tube, go ahead and write up an answer for me to accept.

Not sure if it's your problem, but our one would freeze up in the feed tube because the installation dude put a cheap piercing fitting in to feed it so the feed rate was too slow.
I put a proper soldered copper T and valve in there and no more trouble. Soldering was a bit of PITA because the water kept dripping down the tube- used the white bread trick to deal with that.

Ours is a 1/4-turn shutoff valve. When I disconnected it and turned the water on (with a bucket handy) water came spewing out, so I'm pretty sure the supply is OK.

If so that leaves the solenoid or the control board. If there is full voltage across the solenoid then it's probably not the board.

warning !!! ... do not touch the control board with your hands ... the control board is very likely to have line level voltage on all of its components

@jsotola Plus if you accidentally short it to ground things will not be improved.
